# How to split vendors and polyfills in Webpack4

Tags: webpack

I have two entry points: `main` and `polyfills`.
In Webpack3 I had this configuration:

```
  new CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'polyfills',
    chunks: ['polyfills']
  }),

  // This enables tree shaking of the vendor modules
  new CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    chunks: ['main'],
    minChunks: module => /node_modules/.test(module.resource)
  }),
```

Which allowed me to split vendors from main and leave polyfills intact.
Which in my opinion makes sense because main chunk is too big.

In Webpack4 with no additional config main chunk will not be split.
When I add:

```
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: "all"
  }
},
```

My main chunk will be split. But my polyfills chunk will be also split! Into one containing everything from vendors and one very small which is actual entry point of my app.

How to split main chunk but leave polyfills intact? Or it doesn't make any sense and I won't get any profit from it?

UPD: I can't find a lot of info on what all these spliChunks/cacheGroups/minChunks mean. Are there any docs?

Answer (score -1):

[For webpack4, I guess you are looking for something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqzvy.png)

This is the webpack documentation I found (link where the screenshot belongs to)- 
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/

So instead of chunks:'all', you need to specify the chunks you want to exclude from splitting.

Comment: Please not use external image links as part of your answer, as they might be unavailable in the future.